# JQuery Combobox trigger another event

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, triggers, event-handling

I have combobox jquery for autocomplete my dropdown list. I also have 2 input fields that disabled. If the combobox value is new, it will enable these 2 input fields. Any solution how to do this? My code so far:

```js
(function($) {
  $.widget("custom.combobox", {
    _create: function() {
      this.wrapper = $("<span>")
        .addClass("custom-combobox")
        .insertAfter(this.element);

      this.element.hide();
      this._createAutocomplete();
      this._createShowAllButton();
    },
    _createAutocomplete: function() {
      var selected = this.element.children(":selected"),
        value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

      this.input = $("<input>")
        .appendTo(this.wrapper)
        .val(value)
        .attr("title", "")
        .attr("id", "sicombo")
        .addClass("form-control custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")
        .autocomplete({
          delay: 0,
          minLength: 0,
          source: $.proxy(this, "_source")
        })
        .tooltip({
          tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
        });

      this._on(this.input, {
        autocompleteselect: function(event, ui) {
          ui.item.option.selected = true;
          this._trigger("select", event, {
            item: ui.item.option
          });
        },
        autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
      });
    },
    _createShowAllButton: function() {
      var input = this.input,
        wasOpen = false;

      $("<a>")
        .attr("tabIndex", -1)
        .attr("title", "Show All Items")
        .attr("id", "sicombo2")
        .tooltip()
        .appendTo(this.wrapper)
        .button({
          icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
          },
          text: false
        })
        .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
        .addClass("custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right")
        .mousedown(function() {
          wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
        })
        .click(function() {
          input.focus();

          // Close if already visible
          if (wasOpen) {
            return;
          }

          // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
          input.autocomplete("search", "");
        });
    },
    _source: function(request, response) {
      var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
      response(this.element.children("option").map(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
          return {
            label: text,
            value: text,
            option: this
          };
      }));
    },
    _removeIfInvalid: function(event, ui) {

      // Selected an item, nothing to do
      if (ui.item) {
        return;
      }

      // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
      var value = this.input.val(),
        valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
        valid = false;
      this.element.children("option").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase) {
          this.selected = valid = true;
          return false;
        }
      });

      // Found a match, nothing to do
      if (valid) {
        return;
      }

      // Remove invalid value
      this.input
        .val("")
        .attr("title", value + " didn't match any item")
        .tooltip("open");
      this.element.val("");
      this._delay(function() {
        this.input.tooltip("close").attr("title", "");
      }, 2500);
      this.input.autocomplete("instance").term = "";
    },
    _destroy: function() {
      this.wrapper.remove();
      this.element.show();
    }
  });
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
  $("#combobox123").combobox();
});

$(function() {
  $("input:text[name=browser]").attr("disabled", true);
  $("input:text[name=idbrowser]").attr("disabled", true);

  $('select[name=brow]').on('change', function() {
    $("input:text[name=browser]").attr("disabled", ($(this).val() === 'new') ? false : true);
    $("input:text[name=idbrowser]").attr("disabled", ($(this).val() === 'new') ? false : true);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<select name="brow" class="form-control" id="combobox123">
  <option value="">-- Choose --</option>
  <option value="new">Create New</option>
  <option value="chrome">Google Chrome</option>
  <option value="firefox">Mozilla Firefox</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="idbrowser" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="browser" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use autocompleteselect event of jQuery autocomplete.

Replace following code

```
$('select[name=brow]').on('change', function() {
    $("input:text[name=browser]").attr("disabled", ($(this).val() === 'new') ? false : true);
    $("input:text[name=idbrowser]").attr("disabled", ($(this).val() === 'new') ? false : true);
  });
```

With

```
$( "#sicombo" ).on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {
     $("input:text[name=browser]").attr("disabled", (ui.item.option.value === 'new') ? false : true);
     $("input:text[name=idbrowser]").attr("disabled", (ui.item.option.value === 'new') ? false : true);
  });
```